# How to use simple npm-install in Openshift?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I'm trying to use cute-files on my openshift account

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cute-files

I know node.js works as I did in localhost:3000 but not as expert,

I'm ended up with http://cutefiles-powerupware.rhcloud.com/ that's not I'm looking it. It should be Cute-files app as start.

I did PuTTY to access terminal to do npm-install but no luck due to permission.

The problem is... I cannot understand how openshift works, I need to know how to access console to do npm-install then, execute "$ cute-files", alternativley I've used Git to commit and push, the files are updated...I got no results...  I've spent like 6 or 7 hours, Openshift has been very complicated me to use, can anyone explain how to install and execute simple node.js app in openshift?

Answer (score 4):

It's not like you can access Openshift and *run* any command. Openshift isn't a simple hosting or vps service, it's a PaaS. That means they offer you an environment to run certain services in particular as you demand.

When you create an app it's bound to a git repository which when pushed will be deployed to openshift.

About your application being deployed and runned, it's **NOT** about node.js running in port 3000. Openshift has some default application file names and port to expect.

So, working in a local clone of such repository you might perform the `npm install` command, that will download the `node_modules` folder to be there.

#### How to do all this?

1. First you should install [`rhc`](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-client-tools.html) in your system.
2. Manage to clone any of you applications via rhc.
3. Make changes, and *do git*.
4. Those changes may include doing npm install getting your dependencies.
5. When doing `git push`, expect the changes to be deployed.

You really should read this [guide](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-modifying-applications.html).

Comment: That's exactly I was doing with Git, I've used npm install on my local computer and push to server, it won't run in server as it executed on my local computer, I found no solution, you might install cute-files with your openshift using your Git and you will understand, I will give you +1 if you manage to fix how to execute cute-files in openshift server.

Comment: Hey! I retract! Again, Openshift it's a VPS and you might not have file system privileges at all. Try logging your errors to anywhere and you'll find out

Comment: I mean, cute-files maps your file system to a Web interface, what you just don't and can't have in Openshift

Comment: Basically, I had error with sudo permission, however, let me find simple node.js app which is not involved with file system

Comment: Because perhaps something cute-files is attempting to do is only sudo permisible

Comment: What's about it? https://github.com/amirrajan/nodejs-against-humanity it doesn't say anything about deploying in Openshift