# 'npm install' Error , Openshift

Tags: npm, redhat, yo

When I try to install **Yo** with npm in openshift I got following Error How to fixed it and Use sudo in Openshift for using npm:

```
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding your situation the OS is prompting you to run the command in admin mode. I am not familiar with openshift but it is redhat product and I have experience with fedora so you can try this, Run "su" command, It will prompt you to enter admin password, provide the admin credentials. I hope after that you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you, Openshift is a Paas service So i can't use "su" or any permission command, Do you have any idea about it how to install npm ?

Comment: Ah! well than sorry for answering without researching about openshift. But this might help you if you haven't came across this before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713212/how-to-use-simple-npm-install-in-openshift