# npm install on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, webpack, openshift

I'm completely new to OpenShift and have a hard time navigating docs, as a lot of resources concern `rhc` which has been deprecated since. So I created an app from a private github repo, which runs fine on my localhost. To launch it I run first `npm install`, and then `npm run dev`.

Now when I expose my OpenShift app via their web console, it seems that OpenShift doesn't execute these commands, as when I open the public url of my app I see on the Chrome developer console that the `bundle.js` throws a 404.

I am completely unfamiliar with both `OpenShift` and `Node.js`. How do I fix this, what's the proper way to deploy my app? I have seen in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28713484/1509744) on SO that I should run the install on my localhost and upload all the resulting files to github, but that sounds suspicious to me...

**edit** I just added the `bundle.js` to my repo and it now runs alright on OpenShift... Is this how I am *supposed* to be doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Take a quick look at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/using_images/s2i_images/nodejs.html for some background on Node builds.

Basically, when you create your application from a source repo, it gets cloned into a container and then an `assemble` script runs. For NodeJS 10, this script is here: https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/blob/master/10/s2i/bin/assemble

Once that completes, it gets committed to the internal container registry. Once fully committed, this triggers a deployment config to pull the newly built image, and then it will run the `run` script, here: https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/blob/master/10/s2i/bin/run

Most of the OpenShift builds can be configured by environment variables set either on the build config or deployment config. They are usually documented in the s2i's README: https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/blob/master/10/README.md

Finally, you can override any of these scripts in your own repo by creating either a `run` or `assemble` script in a `.s2i/bin/` directory at the root of your repo.

You can find a lot of great, generic s2i information here: https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image/blob/master/README.md